# How can I turn list of strings to list of lists?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I am new in programming and in stackoverflow. Sorry is this seems too basic.
I am trying to turn this:

I am trying to train a AI for predicting destination a car based on historical data.
It is inside a column and I must iterate over all of them.
I a single list it is working, but in a column, it is not for some reason.

I am trying this on windows 10 in anaconda , jupyter notebook

I am trying to turn this:

```
lst = ['55.7492,12.5405', '55.7492,12.5405', '55.7492,12.5406', '55.7492,12.5406']
```

into this

```
lst = [[55.7492,12.5405], [55.7492,12.5405], [55.7492,12.5406], [55.7492,12.5406]]
```

I have a column with a lot of those in a csv file.

I tryed to turn them like this:

```
[[x] for x in lst]

[['55.7492,12.5405'],
 ['55.7492,12.5405'],
 ['55.7492,12.5406'],
 ['55.7492,12.5406']]
```

So its working find outside of the csv but when I try to do it for every box in the colomn:

```
for stuff in data['column']:
    [[x] for x in stuff]

for stuff in data_train['locations']:
    [map(int,x.split()) for x in stuff]
```

Nothing changes in the column .

Comment: You never assign anything in your loops, so it's no wonder that nothing changes.

Answer (score 2):

Use `apply` with list comprehension for split each value of list by `,` and cast to `float`s:

```
lst = ['55.7492,12.5405', '55.7492,12.5405', '55.7492,12.5406', '55.7492,12.5406']
df = pd.DataFrame({'column':[lst,lst]})

df['locations'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x: [list(map(float,y.split(','))) for y in x])
print (df)

                                              column  \
0  [55.7492,12.5405, 55.7492,12.5405, 55.7492,12....   
1  [55.7492,12.5405, 55.7492,12.5405, 55.7492,12....   

                                           locations  
0  [[55.7492, 12.5405], [55.7492, 12.5405], [55.7...  
1  [[55.7492, 12.5405], [55.7492, 12.5405], [55.7...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the output of your list comprehension:

```
for col in columns:  # where columns is a list of your columns
    data[col] = [[x] for x in data[col]]
```

or just on one column, it's enough to do:

```
data_train['locations'] = [map(int,x.split()) for x in data_train['locations']]
```

Because `data['column']` is a list of elements, and when you loop over it, `stuff` will be a different row element at each iteration, so not a list.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
New = [str(val).split(",") for val in lst]
print(New)
```

Output:

```
[['55.7492', '12.5405'], ['55.7492', '12.5405'], ['55.7492', '12.5406'], ['55.7492', '12.5406']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most efficient way is to use [ast.literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast-helpers):

```
import ast
y = [list(ast.literal_eval(x)) for x in lst]
```

Now if you have a column with list of strings which is to be converted to list of lists then you may use:

```
df['new_col'] =df['col'].apply(lambda x: [list(ast.literal_eval(y)) for y in x ])
```